# How do I increment this variable contained between two strings?

Tags: javascript

I want the following code to output number++ in the middle of the two strings, I will use 33 as an example so the output should be 34

```
let number = prompt('what is your favorite number')

if (number == 42) {
  response = "Yay, that's an excellent number!"
} else if (number <= 42) {
 response = "Eh, that's an alright number but " + (number++) + " would be a better number"
} else {
 response = "No. That number is far too big"
}

console.log(response)
```

//Current outputs

```
= 42 "Yay, that's an excellent number!"
<= 42 "Eh, that's an alright number but 33 would be a better number"
else "No. That number is far too big"
```

//Expected output

```
<=42 "Eh, that's an alright number but 34 would be a better number"
```

Comment: pre-increment fixed it thanks guys! forgot about pre and post increments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Increment (++)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment)

> The increment operator increments (adds one to) its operand and returns a value.
>
> 1. If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, `x++`), then it increments and ***returns the value before incrementing***.
> 2. If used prefix, with operator before operand (for example, `++x`), then it increments and ***returns the value after incrementing***.

Instead of post-increment (`number++`) you have to use pre-increment (`++number`)

```js
let number = prompt('what is your favorite number')

if (number == 42) {
  response = "Yay, that's an excellent number!"
} else if (number <= 42) {
 response = "Eh, that's an alright number but " + (++number) + " would be a better number"
} else {
 response = "No. That number is far too big"
}

console.log(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use pre increment `++number`, so the increased number is returned before it's evaluated and displayed.

```js
let number = prompt('what is your favorite number')

if (number == 42) {
  response = "Yay, that's an excellent number!"
} else if (number <= 42) {
 response = "Eh, that's an alright number but " + (++number) + " would be a better number"
} else {
 response = "No. That number is far too big"
}

console.log(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pre-increment as others have suggested would certainly work (and is I guess the correct answer to the question *as stated*), but reading your code, it seems that your actual intention is not to modify the number that was provided, but to present the integer immediately following the provided number.

I would advocate presenting it in the following manner:

```
response = "Eh, that's an alright number but " + (number+1) + " would be a better number";
```

Altering the number, in your code example, seems to be an undesirable *side effect*. It may *happen to be* that the actual provided `number` is no longer of interest after presenting this information, but one day you'll want to also add it to a list of numbers attempted, or return the number to do something else, and you'll have to remember to decrement the number.